# Generating WSDL with NuSOAP - return struct with various types (int, string, array of structs)

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I would like to query some stuffs via SOAP by generating WSDL with [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).
I know there are lots of questions related to the topic, but I didn't have success to adapt the codes to my particular problem.

I was successful in generating WSDL code which returns just an array of structs (associative array), BUT **I would rather like to return an object (struct) which contains an integer variable, a string variable AND an array of structs**.

So, **this is the code that works for returning an array of structs**:

```php
<?php

    function getStuffs( $user='', $pass='' ) {
        // here we can check user and pass and do whatever (if it isn't alright, we can throw exception or return NULL or sg. similar)
        // .......

        $stuff_array   = array();
        $stuff_array[] = array( 'id'=>122, 'name'=>'One stuff');
        $stuff_array[] = array( 'id'=>213, 'name'=>'Another stuff');
        $stuff_array[] = array( 'id'=>435, 'name'=>'Whatever stuff');
        $stuff_array[] = array( 'id'=>65, 'name'=>'Cool Stuff');
        $stuff_array[] = array( 'id'=>92, 'name'=>'Wow, what a stuff');    

        return $stuff_array;
    }

    require_once 'nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
    $server = new soap_server;

    // $myNamespace = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
    $myNamespace = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $server->configureWSDL('MyStuffService', 'urn:' . $myNamespace);
    // $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        // name
        'Stuffs',
        // typeClass (complexType|simpleType|attribute)
        'complexType',
        // phpType: currently supported are array and struct (php assoc array)
        'struct',
        // compositor (all|sequence|choice)
        'all',
        // restrictionBase namespace:name (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array)
        '',
        // elements = array ( name = array(name=>'',type=>'') )
        array(
            'id' => array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => 'xsd:int'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => 'xsd:string'
            )
        )
    );  

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        // name
        'StuffsArray',
        // typeClass (complexType|simpleType|attribute)
        'complexType',
        // phpType: currently supported are array and struct (php assoc array)
        'array',
        // compositor (all|sequence|choice)
        '',
        // restrictionBase namespace:name (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array)
        'SOAP-ENC:Array',
        // elements = array ( name = array(name=>'',type=>'') )
        array(),
        // attrs
        array(
            array(
                'ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
                'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Stuffs[]'
            )
        ),
        // arrayType: namespace:name (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string)
        'tns:Stuffs'
    );

    $server->register(
        // string $name the name of the PHP function, class.method or class..method
        'getStuffs',
        // array $in assoc array of input values: key = param name, value = param type
        array(
            'user' => 'xsd:string',
            'pass' => 'xsd:string'
        ),
        // array $out assoc array of output values: key = param name, value = param type
        array(
            'return' => 'tns:StuffsArray'
        ),
        // mixed $namespace the element namespace for the method or false
        'urn:' . $myNamespace,
        // mixed $soapaction the soapaction for the method or false
        'urn:' . $myNamespace . "#getStuffs",
        // mixed $style optional (rpc|document) or false Note: when 'document' is specified, parameter and return wrappers are created for you automatically
        'rpc',
        // mixed $use optional (encoded|literal) or false
        'encoded',
        // string $documentation optional Description to include in WSDL
        'Fetch array of Stuffs ("id", "name").' // documentation
    );

    #$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $myNamespace;
    $server->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');
    exit();

?>
```

In a C# Console Application, after adding a Web Reference called "StuffService" with the "?wsdl" appended to the appropriate URL where this PHP-file can be found, this code works, I can perfectly query the stuff_array values like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WebServiceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StuffService.MyStuffService myService = new StuffService.MyStuffService();

            StuffService.Stuffs[] stuffs = myService.getStuffs("someone", "1234");

            foreach (var stuff in stuffs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stuff.id+".: "+stuff.name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

That's cool, BUT I'd like to develop this code to give back an object like this:

```php
class ResponseObject {
    public $responseCode = 0;
    public $responseMessage = '';
    public $stuffArray = NULL;
}   

$responseObject = NULL;

function getStuffs( $user='', $pass='' ) {
    global $responseObject;

    $responseObject = new ResponseObject();

    // check stuffs in a simple way now
    if($user != 'someone' && $pass != '1234'){
        $responseObject->responseCode = 2;
        $responseObject->responseMessage = 'Authentication failed';
        return $responseObject;
    }

    $responseObject->stuffArray   = array();
    $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>122, 'name'=>'One stuff');
    $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>213, 'name'=>'Another stuff');
    $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>435, 'name'=>'Whatever stuff');
    $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>65, 'name'=>'Cool Stuff');
    $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>92, 'name'=>'Wow, what a stuff');          

    $responseObject->responseCode = 1;
    $responseObject->responseMessage = 'Successful!';
    return $responseObject; 
}
```

What's the appropriate NuSOAP code for that?
Thanks!! :)

I hope I could clarify what I would like to achieve: returning a struct which contains an int, a string and an array of structs, but don't know how to write the appropriate NuSOAP-code for that.  This way I could firstly check the responseCode, and handle it with the appropriate error messages OR outputting the stuffArray, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After long hours of experimentation, I found the solution!

So giving back a structure containing three members - an int responseCode, a string responseMessage and an array of structs called stuffArray in the example - via SOAP with NuSOAP (PHP) looks like this below, I put some comments in the code to make it more unambiguous:

```php
<?php

    class ResponseObject {
        public $responseCode = 0;
        public $responseMessage = 'Unknown error!';
        public $stuffArray = NULL;
    }   

    /**
     * @return object
     */ 
    function getStuffs( $user='', $pass='' ) {

        $responseObject = new ResponseObject();

        // check stuffs in a simple way now
        if( !($user == 'someone' and $pass == '1234') ){
            $responseObject->responseCode = 2;
            $responseObject->responseMessage = 'Authentication failed!';
            return $responseObject;
        }

        $responseObject->stuffArray   = array();
        $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>122, 'name'=>'One stuff');
        $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>213, 'name'=>'Another stuff');
        $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>435, 'name'=>'Whatever stuff');
        $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>65, 'name'=>'Cool Stuff');
        $responseObject->stuffArray[] = array( 'id'=>92, 'name'=>'Wow, what a stuff');          

        $responseObject->responseCode = 1;
        $responseObject->responseMessage = 'Successful!';
        return $responseObject; 
    }

    require_once 'nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
    $server = new soap_server;

    // $myNamespace = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
    $myNamespace = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $server->configureWSDL(
        // string $serviceName, name of the service
        'MyStuffService',
        // mixed $namespace optional 'tns' service namespace or false
        // 'urn:' . $myNamespace
        $myNamespace
    );

    // $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $myNamespace;

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        // name
        'Stuffs',
        // typeClass (complexType|simpleType|attribute)
        'complexType',
        // phpType: currently supported are array and struct (php assoc array)
        'struct',
        // compositor (all|sequence|choice)
        'all',
        // restrictionBase namespace:name (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array)
        '',
        // elements = array ( name = array(name=>'',type=>'') )
        array(
            'id' => array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => 'xsd:int'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => 'xsd:string'
            )
        )
    );  

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        // name
        'StuffsArray',
        // typeClass (complexType|simpleType|attribute)
        'complexType',
        // phpType: currently supported are array and struct (php assoc array)
        'array',
        // compositor (all|sequence|choice)
        '',
        // restrictionBase namespace:name (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array)
        'SOAP-ENC:Array',
        // elements = array ( name = array(name=>'',type=>'') )
        array(),
        // attrs
        array(
            array(
                'ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
                'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Stuffs[]'
            )
        ),
        // arrayType: namespace:name (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string)
        'tns:Stuffs'
    );


    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        // name
        'ResponseObject',
        // typeClass (complexType|simpleType|attribute)
        'complexType',
        // phpType: currently supported are array and struct (php assoc array)
        'struct',
        // compositor (all|sequence|choice)
        'all',
        // restrictionBase namespace:name (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array)
        '',
        // elements = array ( name = array(name=>'',type=>'') )
        array
        (
            'responseCode' => array(   'type' => 'xsd:int'),
            'responseMessage' => array(   'type' => 'xsd:string'),
            'stuffArray'   => array(   'type' => 'tns:StuffsArray'
                                            // DON'T UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES, BECAUSE THIS WAY IT DOESN'T WORK!!! - Left it in the code not to forget it....
                                            // ,
                                            // 'minOccurs' => '0',
                                            // 'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded'
                                            )
        )
    );

    $server->register(
        // string $name the name of the PHP function, class.method or class..method
        'getStuffs',
        // array $in assoc array of input values: key = param name, value = param type
        array(
            'user' => 'xsd:string',
            'pass' => 'xsd:string'
        ),
        // array $out assoc array of output values: key = param name, value = param type
        array(
            'return' => 'tns:ResponseObject'
        ),
        // mixed $namespace the element namespace for the method or false
        // 'urn:' . $myNamespace,
        $myNamespace,
        // mixed $soapaction the soapaction for the method or false
        // 'urn:' . $myNamespace . "#getStuffs",
        $myNamespace . "#getStuffs",
        // mixed $style optional (rpc|document) or false Note: when 'document' is specified, parameter and return wrappers are created for you automatically
        'rpc',
        // mixed $use optional (encoded|literal) or false
        'encoded',
        // string $documentation optional Description to include in WSDL
        'Fetch array of Stuffs ("id", "name").' // documentation
    );

    // $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $myNamespace;

    // function def.: nusoap/lib/class.soap_server.php (236)
    $server->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');

    //   DON'T UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINES!! - Don't call these headers explicitly,
    //   everything will be handled in function service() appropriately - I know it by experience that it's not a good choice...
    // output:wsdl
    // header('Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8');
    // header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    // echo $server->wsdl->serialize();

    exit(0);
```

---

Give this file a name, for example `getStuffComplex.php`, and then copy this file somewhere on your webserver, and remember its path.
For example one domain name on my local webserver is `http://soap.local`, and the above mentioned PHP-code can be reached at `http://soap.local/getStuffComplex.php`.

Let's say you want to **call getStuffs() function in a C# code via a SOAP client, from a Console Application under Visual Studio 2010**. In this case you have to do the following steps:

1. Create a new Console Application project
2. Right click *"References" - "Add Service Reference"*
3. Click *"Advanced..."*
4. Click *"Add Web Reference..."*
5. Paste the path of the previously saved PHP-file's URL (with the content above) and append the "?wsdl" string in the URL field. For example in my case: `http://soap.local/getStuffComplex.php?wsdl`
6. Click the green right arrow (*"Go"*) or hit Enter after fill out URL field. If getStuff() method is found, the situation is hopeful.
7. Give the reference a name on the right side (Web reference name), for example *"StuffServiceComplex"* (I will use this name in my code), than hit Enter. Now you have to see it under *"Web References"*.
8. Copy the code below into Program.cs, and test it by hitting F5 or clicking the green "play" icon.

The C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

namespace WebServiceTestComplex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                StuffServiceComplex.MyStuffService myService = new StuffServiceComplex.MyStuffService();

                StuffServiceComplex.ResponseObject myRespObject = myService.getStuffs("someone", "1234");

                switch (myRespObject.responseCode)
                {
                    // Everything was OK, results can be output
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Everything's OK, let's write the results to the standard output:");
                        foreach (var stuff in myRespObject.stuffArray)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t"+stuff.id + ".:\t" + stuff.name);
                        }
                        break;
                    // Authentication failed
                    case 2:
                    // Unknown error
                    case 0:
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Error:");
                        Console.WriteLine("\tError code: "+myRespObject.responseCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("\tError message: " + myRespObject.responseMessage);
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=== SOAP EXCEPTION!! ===");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=== OTHER EXCEPTION!! ===");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Everything's OK, let's write the results to the standard output:
        122.:   One stuff
        213.:   Another stuff
        435.:   Whatever stuff
        65.:    Cool Stuff
        92.:    Wow, what a stuff

Press a key...
```

I hope this helps someone who struggled with bringing PHP and SOAP and .NET together.

(Note: take care about character coding when using accents or any special letters. By default, ANSI could be used (but character encodings have to be the same).)